# pywikipedia (python) regex to add string if lacking

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a set of records like:

Name

- Name Paul Berry: present
- Address George Necky: not present
- Name Bob van Basten: present
- Name Richard Von Rumpy: not present
- Name Daddy Badge: not present
- Name Paul Berry: present
- Street George Necky: not present
- Street Bob van Basten: present
- Name Richard Von Rumpy: not present
- City Daddy Badge: not present

and I want that all the records beginning with *Name* be in the form

- Name *Name Surname*: not present

leaving untouched the records beginnning with other word.

i.e. I want to add the string "not" to the records beginning with *Name* where it isn't. I'm working with python (pywikipediabot)

Trying

```
python replace.py -dotall -regex 'Name ((?!not ).*?)present' 'Name \1not present'
```

but it adds the "not" even where it is already present.

Perhaps I haven't understood the negative lookahead syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look for `: present` and replace it with `: not present`.

**Edit:** Improved answer:

```
for line in lines:
    m = re.match('^Name[^:]*: present', line)
    if m:
        print re.sub(': present', ': not present', line)
    else:
       print line
```

Comment: well, the real case is more complex, and it isn't possible to use this solution

Comment: So please post your real case.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it:

```
re.sub(r'(Name.*?)(not )?present$', r'\1not present', s)
```

Comment: Indeed: This simply starts the match after the "not " when it is present.

Comment: @PaoloBenvenuto: I've updated my answer to match the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "negative look-behind" expression. This substitution will work:

```
'Name (.*)(?<!not )present' -> 'Name \1not present'
```

The .* matches everything between "Name" and "present", but the whole regexp matches only if "present" is not preceded by "not".

And are you sure you need `-dotall`? It looks like you want `.*` to match *within* a line only.

Comment: Was confused by my own testing text-- this should now be correct

Comment: The actual code I use is `python replace.py -dotall -start="San Pietro" -regex '(\{\{Sezione accessoria\|.*?)(?<!Sezioni accessorie fine)\[\[Categoria:' '\1{{Sezioni accessorie fine}}\n\n[[Categoria:'`, but I cannot get it working: it adds the text even where it shouldn't.

Comment: Ugh. I can't even tell what you're trying to replace with what. Does replace.py do the right thing with the example in your question and my regexp?

Comment: Well, actually there is a problem in the way pywikipediabot manages the new lines: when you tell the bot to insert a `\n`, it actually inserts a `\r\n`. So the solution is rigth. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that! (You're now supposed to flag the best answer for future viewers by "accepting" it.)